# Crossover detection in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, relational-database, mysql-workbench

If there is a Table is MySQL which contains three columns one is a date, and the other two are Quantity 1 and Quantity 2. I am trying to find all the Date's where the curve plotted by Quantity 1 Vs Date crosses Quantity 2 Vs Date? And the problem is sometimes the data might not encompass the points where the crossover takes place, in that case, I should find the Dates soon after the crossover Is there any way in which I can do this in MySQL?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Do you have access to MySQL 8+ ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, appreciate that the marker for the two curves crossing is that, at a given date, one of the two conditions is true:

- The first curve is greater than the second curve, and at the immediately previous date, the second curve was greater than the first curve, or
- The reverse of the above is true

Given that you have access to MySQL 8+, we can try using the `LAG` analytic function here:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '2018-01-01' AS date, 1 AS quantity1, 5 AS quantity2 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-02', 3, 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-03', 4, 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-04', 2, 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-05', 4, 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-06', 9, 8
),
cte AS (
    SELECT
        date, quantity1, quantity2,
        LAG(quantity1) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS q1lag,
        LAG(quantity2) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS q2lag
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    date
FROM cte
WHERE
    (quantity1 > quantity2 AND q1lag < q2lag) OR
    (quantity2 > quantity1 AND q2lag < q1lag);
```

[image]

Here is chart of the sample time series data:

[image]

It should be clear that on each of the three dates in the result set, the two time series crossed each other as compared from the immediately previous date.

### Demo

Note that this will produce the greater value of a pair of dates during which the two charts crossed.  In general, a cross would happen in between two dates.

**Edit:**

If your MySQL version is earlier than 8+, then we would have to use another way to find the `LAG`.  One option is to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT date
FROM
(
    SELECT
        date, quantity1, quantity2,
        (SELECT quantity1 FROM yourTable t2
         WHERE t2.date < t1.date ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 1) AS q1lag,
        (SELECT quantity2 FROM yourTable t2
         WHERE t2.date < t1.date ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 1) AS q2lag
   FROM yourTable t1
) t
WHERE
    (quantity1 > quantity2 AND q1lag < q2lag) OR
    (quantity2 > quantity1 AND q2lag < q1lag);
```

### Demo

Comment: @TimBiegeleiseni I ran the above code in the MySQL workbench 8.0 it generates error 1064.

Comment: @RamSuryaSriShourieMummadav I don't know what to say.  It runs in a MySQL 8 demo with no problems.  Are you sure you are using MySQL 8 or higher?

Comment: I am using MYSQL Workbench 8.0 isn't it equivalent to MySQL 8

Comment: Yes, you should be fine.  What is the exact error message?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'yourTable AS (     SELECT '2018-01-01' AS date, 1 AS quantity1, 5 AS quantity2 U' at line 1

Comment: Can you run this: `WITH cte AS (SELECT 1 AS id) SELECT * FROM cte`?  It looks like you either left out `WITH` or maybe CTEs are not supported on your MySQL version.  Please use the demo to see that the code works for MySQL 8.

Comment: @TimBiegeleiseni Sorry, I just realised that when workbench updates it doesn't update the MySQL, so my MySQL version is 5.7.13. I am really sorry for your effort my mysql version is lower than 8 .

Comment: I added an alternative query at the bottom which should run on earlier versions of MySQL.  The rest of my answer doesn't need to change (I think).

Comment: @TimBiegeleiseni This earlier version one is working. Thanks